# How to display the address of the function in WinDBG for .fnret command?

Tags: windbg

I need to get the address of the function required by `.fnret` command in WinDBG.
For example, I want to get the information about return value of apphelp!ApphelpCheckRunApp function.
First, I set a breakpoint on this function:

`bp apphelp!ApphelpCheckRunApp`

Then I'm continuing the execution, until it breaks on that function.

After breaking, I'm executing `.fnret [Address]` command.

I already tried to use the `77b345d5` address displayed on the breakpoint:

```
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=77b345d5 ebx=7ed320f5 ecx=7ffac000 edx=7c886920 esi=7ffac000 edi=00000018
eip=77b345d5 esp=0378ce90 ebp=0378d108 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000213
appHelp!ApphelpCheckRunApp:
77b345d5 8bff            mov     edi,edi
```

but that seems to be not what I need, because I get the following error:

`^ Unknown or unsupported return type in '.fnret 77b345d5'`

Also I used return address `7c818cdf` of this function from call stack (got via `kb` command):

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child
0283ce8c 7c818cdf 00000474 046bb7d0 00000000 appHelp!ApphelpCheckRunApp
```

but it leads me to the same error.

Which WinDBG command I should use for that and which return address it will display (in case it isn't displayed yet on breakpoint)? Will it then properly work for `.fnret` or `.fnret /s` commands? Unfortunately, there are no any examples of using them on MSDN, only the documentation.

Hoping on your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that command is indeed not helpful at all when using public PDBs.
I found better solution here: [How to get return value from a function in windbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025804/how-to-get-return-value-from-a-function-in-windbg).

It is possible to get the memory address of return value by viewing eax/rax register on x86/x64 appropriately, using `r` command (since it always is stored there). After breakpoint, I'm just typing `r eax` on x86 or `r rax` on x64. Output will be look like this:

`eax=[Address]`

Then, I'm displaying a value of received memory address via d* (dd, du etc. displaying data types commands), like this:

`du [Address]`

After looking at the output, it becomes understandable which data is returned, and its data type also (at least in most of cases).
But to understand first, which data type is used, I'm trying the different combinations of [display memory commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/d--da--db--dc--dd--dd--df--dp--dq--du--dw--dw--dyb--dyd--display-memor) and [display referenced memory commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dda--ddp--ddu--dpa--dpp--dpu--dqa--dqp--dqu--display-referenced-memory).

Answer (score 0):

.fnret is only useful if you have private pdb
it is not useful if you have public pdb because it needs to retrieve the type information

here is a sample usage on a compiled code with private pdb

```
0:000> x /t /v /f myst!towlower
prv func   00007ff6`74ba5f84    7 <function> myst!towlower (unsigned short)

0:000> x /t /v /f myst!toupper
prv func   00007ff6`74b91b10   2a <function> myst!toupper (int)

0:000> .fnret myst!towlower
myst!towlower (00007ff6`74ba5f84) = unsigned short 1

0:000> .fnret myst!toupper
myst!toupper (00007ff6`74b91b10) = int 0n1
```

error on a known function which returns a HANDLE  using public stripped pdb

```
0:000> .fnret KERNELBASE!CreateFileA
                                   ^ Unknown or unsupported return type in '.fnret KERNELBASE!CreateFileA'
```

success on a system file with private pdb
it casts the forced return value dumped in @rax as a typed return with value of a function with type information

a system file with prrivate pdb

```
0:000> .printf "%y\n" , 0x00000001`800bace0 ; an arbitrary function
ole32!ToUnicode (00000001`800bace0)
0:000> .printf "%mu\n" , 00000001`8014c17a  ; an arbitrary wide string 
guageErrorPointerംА
0:000> r rax = 00000001`8014c17a  the $retreg is populated with an address of wide string
0:000> .fnret 0x00000001`800bace0  << fnret casts the $retreg as wide string and prints the resulting widestring 
ole32!ToUnicode (00000001`800bace0) = wchar_t * 0x00000001`8014c17a
 "guageErrorPointer???"
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.
So I'm still wondering: can I do the same thing using public PDB symbols (perhaps via another command(s))?

Comment: yeah you can if you know the type with c++ expressions , dx , natvis evaluators etc  for example  dx (wchar_t *) @rax will cast the returned 64 bit numeral into a wide string type

Comment: But what if I don't know the return data type? How can I get it then? I hope to get at least the info about return type (int, bool, char, string etc), not the value itself, if this is not possible in my case.

Comment: Type information is stripped out in public pdbs . so .fnret cant retrieve the return type

Comment: OK, that command is not helpful at all when using public PDBs.
I found better solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025804/how-to-get-return-value-from-a-function-in-windbg. Thanks a lot for your help anyway!

Comment: well $retreg is just platform agnostic return register  which would be either  `@eax for 32 bit ` or  `@rax for 64 bit`. you are welcome